# fluentbit logs are creating over 1000+ streams, how to merge logs if same application but new podname

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

Currently in our environment on EKS we have fluentbit to collect logs and push to Cloudwatch, we noticed that same service that has been redeployed after new code changes that a new log stream is created, this causes over 1000 log streams, we are wondering if we can merge the logstreams to one logstream for 1 application.

E.g:
Application A has POD `A-72371723` running, a logstream is created for that.
Developer pushes new code and Application A is redeployed and has POD Name `A-44444` that then creates a logstream, we want to merge those two logstreams into just 1 and name it `APPLICATION NAME`

Comment: The default fluent bit config is to use pod name in the log stream identifier.  This means different pods of the same deployment will annoyingly have separate log streams.  I haven't found any documentation anywhere on how to change that.  I might have to go back to fluentd